# How to know which cells, or range of cells, are protected in Google Spreadsheet with Google Sheet API?

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I need to read a Google Spreadsheet with the Google-Sheet API, but in addition to read the data I need to know which cells, or range of cells are protected.

Looking in the API documentation I found the way to create, delete or update protected ranges... [(https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/ranges](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/ranges)) but I couldn't find any method that, given a range, can tell me which cells are protected and which are not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Answer:

*You can make a call to `Spreadsheets.get` and view a list of protected ranges in the `sheets/protectedRanges` object key.*

#### More Information:

As per the documentation on [Sheet objects](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/sheets), which is a sub-object of the return from the [`Spreadsheets.get` endpoint](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get):

> #### ProtectedRange
>
> A protected range.
>
> ```
> {
>   "protectedRangeId": integer,
>   "range": {
>     object (GridRange)
>   },
>   "namedRangeId": string,
>   "description": string,
>   "warningOnly": boolean,
>   "requestingUserCanEdit": boolean,
>   "unprotectedRanges": [
>     {
>       object (GridRange)
>     }
>   ],
>   "editors": {
>     object (Editors)
>   }
> }
> ```

The `range` object of this `protectedRange` contains a [`GridRange` object](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/other#GridRange) of the range that is being protected.

#### References:

- [Method: `Spreadsheets.get` | Sheets API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get)
- [Sheets API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/sheets)

  - [`ProtectedRange` Object](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/sheets#protectedrange)
- [`GridRange` - Other | Sheets API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/other#GridRange)